# Android - How to stop Asynchronous call after come back from activated intent?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-maps-android-api-2

I have just playing with Google map direction, in my example I have just using list view, in that list view getting data from Asynchronous call (from hard coded data). List view contains list of Addresses, if any one touch on single address in list view will navigate to Google map GPS of Android phone using below code after click on List item.

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + "" + "&daddr=" + saddr));
startActivity(i);
```

But the problem is After I seeing Google map direction if I click back button its return to my list view Activity, But the Asynchronous call always running its doesn't stop..... How to stop this one.. I have using `progressDialog.dismiss();` in

```
protected void onPostExecute(Exception ex) {

        if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(isCancelled()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }

    }
```

And also I using in

```
@Override
    protected void onCancelled (){
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
```

I have calling progressDialog in

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        // display progress dialog while data is being loaded       
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,    
                "Please wait...", prompt, true);    
    }
```

please help me out...

Comment: Try to dismiss progress dialog after you call startActivity(i) since you do not neet id anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey folks thanks for your Answers, I got it. In `protected void onCancelled ()` I have just called like this type...

```
@Override
    protected void onCancelled (){

        if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dismissing the `ProgressDialog` does not stop your AsyncTask. Use the `public final boolean cancel (boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` method to stop your task.

More infos in [Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29)

Comment: Also check for the cancel flag in you AsyncTask. You can do this via 'isCancelled()'

Comment: @user1396042: then you should call cancel somewhere. You should not override this. You should call cancel() on the AsynTask object that you have.